# Datatables search multiple columns individually

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to do a filter by column in the datatable and I am not getting why the row is only found if it exists in the two columns, I would like that if it had in another column the search would find result.

I tried doing this but when i use this code it only searches the result in the first column, E.g. 4th Column. and ignores the rest.

```
    table.column([4,5]).search($(this).val()).draw();
```

---

```
$("#select-categories").each( function ( i ) {
                var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value="" class="optionGroup">Todas</option></select>')
                      .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
                      .on( 'change', function () {
                          table
                              .column(2).search( $(this).val() )
                              .draw();
                      });



                documentosCatRef.on('value', function(data){
                  categoria = data.val();
                  for(var cat in categoria){
                    subcategoria = categoria[cat].subcategorias
                    select.append( '<option value="'+categoria[cat].titulo+'" class="optionGroup">'+categoria[cat].titulo+'</option>'+carregaSubcategoria(subcategoria)+'')
                  }
                })

                function carregaSubcategoria(subcategoria){
                  a = []
                  i = 0;
                  option = ""
                  for(var subcats in subcategoria){
                    a[i] = subcategoria[subcats].nome
                    i++
                  }
                  i = 0;
                  for (var subcat in a){
                  option += '<option value="'+a[subcat]+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+a[subcat]+'</option>'
                  }
                  return option;
                }
              });
```

---

```
<div id="tableCustom_filter" class="dataTables_wrapper.no-footer dataTables_filter">
            <label style="display: inline-block;">Filtrar por Categoria:</label>
            <div style="display: inline-block;" id="select-categories"></div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`columns().search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().search()) to search in multiple columns.

```
table.columns([4,5]).search($(this).val()).draw();
```

Comment: I used the colums but it only returns if the item is in the two columns. He does not look at them individually.

Comment: This is an AND search between the columns.  If you want to create an OR search between the columns then you need to create a [Search Plugin](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search) that will perform the search how you want.